# Marklogic 9 with Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, marklogic, mlcp

I integrated ML 9 with hadoop using marklogic connector. I want to load data from my local machine to marklogic using hadoop . In the [Document](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_25141) they had mentioned there are two ways to load data using hadoop

1. Importing data from HDFS to ML using MLCP
2. Exporting data from ML to HDFS using MLCP

   What i want to know is there any way to send data from MLCP to ML directly though my hadoop because i want to use the mapreduce power of hadoop by giving `input_split` , `-max_split_size` etc . I know MLCP is build in mapreduce since my hadoop cluster has much processing power i want to use it.

Thanks